# C# Reading from html and inputting into .Text

Tags: c#, html

I'm currently trying to read from an HTML file hosted online. My code should read to the end and then change `xylosNotice1.Text` to the source read from the HTML file.

Here is what I've tried:

```
WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/UpdateMe/updates.html");
req.Method = "GET";

string source;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
    source = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

Console.WriteLine(source);
xylosNotice1.Text = (source);
```

It doesn't update the textbox with the source.

Comment: When you debug this, what's in `source`?  Setting the property will definitely set the property.  Are you sure this code is executing when you think it is?  Are you sure the values are what you expect them to be?

Comment: Can you show how you call this method? You may be having a cross-threading issue.

Comment: What type of project is this? ASP.NET? MVC? WPF? WinForms?

Comment: well when debugging it shows nothing and in outputs reads nothing.

Comment: it's a windowsForm project.

Comment: also this code is just placed in the actual xyloseNotice1 code

Comment: Hmm... tested this code with Google site. No errors. Source is loaded to textbox.

Comment: then why wouldn't it work for me?

Comment: With your address i have got "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found".

Comment: Yeah because my site isn't example.com but I did resolve this seems I was to put this code in the Main_Load part, I'm so stupid and tired haha

Comment: I'm assuming then you had it in the constructor, possibly before the "InitializeComponent" call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys stupid mistake, The code needed to be placed in the Main_Load part this is resolved.